# Не работает тег viewport

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка, viewport

Не могу понять, в чем причина. Не первый сайт верстаю, да и не сайт, так, заказчику хотел показать пример калькулятора на его сайт.
При сужении окна браузера контент не адаптируется, а масштабируется, как если бы viewport не было.
Делал с шаблона, с которым ни разу таких проблем не было.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я туплю?

Адрес:
https://sah.vybordela.kz/kalkulyator-potolkov/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>Калькулятор потолков</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="calculator" id="calculator">
        <div class="calculator-grid">

            <div class="calculator-item">
                <label class="calculator-item--label" for="material">Материал</label>
                <select class="calculator-item--field" id="material" type="text" onchange="calculate()">
                    <option value="ПВХ">ПВХ</option>
                    <option value="Ткань">Ткань</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="calculator-item">
                <label class="calculator-item--label" for="room_length">Длина потолка</label>
                <input class="calculator-item--field" id="room_length" type="number" onchange="calculate()" value=0>
            </div>
            <div class="calculator-item">
                <label class="calculator-item--label" for="room_width">Ширина потолка</label>
                <input class="calculator-item--field" id="room_width" type="number" onchange="calculate()" value=0>
            </div>
            <div class="calculator-item">
                <label class="calculator-item--label" for="number_of_corners">Количество углов</label>
                <input class="calculator-item--field" id="number_of_corners" type="number" onchange="calculate()" value=4>
            </div>
            <div class="calculator-item">
                <label class="calculator-item--label" for="number_of_lights">Количество светильников</label>
                <input class="calculator-item--field" id="number_of_lights" type="number" onchange="calculate()" value=1>
            </div>
            <div class="calculator-item">
                <label class="calculator-item--label" for="number_of_pipes">Количество труб</label>
                <input class="calculator-item--field" id="number_of_pipes" type="number" onchange="calculate()" value=1>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="calculator-footer">
            <div class="calculator-footer--item calculator-footer--sum">
                <div>Итог: </div>
                <div id="calculator_sum">0</div>
            </div>
            <button class="button" id="calculator_button" style="display:none;">Рассчитать</button>
            <div class="calculator-footer--item calculator-footer--gift">
                <div>Подарок: </div>
                <div id="calculator_gift">&nbsp;</div>  
            </div>
            <div class="calculator-footer--item calculator-footer--discount" style="display:none;">
                <div>Скидка: </div>
                <div id="calculator_discount">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus, :active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus, a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav, footer, header, aside {
  display: block;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input, button, textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
}

html {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.calculator {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 420px;
  width: 100%;
}
.calculator-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: end;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.calculator-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.calculator-item--label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.calculator-item--field {
  /* height: 1.5em; */
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 8px 5px 8px 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.calculator-item--field[type=number] {
  text-align: end;
}
.calculator-footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr); */
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
.calculator-footer--sum,
.calculator-footer--gift,
.calculator-footer--discount {
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; */
}
.calculator-footer--sum > *:nth-child(2) { 
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.calculator-footer--item > div:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
  text-align: end;
}
.button {
  background-color: rgb(137, 231, 255);
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;

}
.calculator-gift {
}
.calculator-discount {
}

@media all and (max-width:400px) {
  .calculator {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .calculator-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас опечатка.
У вас:
`<meta id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Должно быть:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Блин. Спасибо. Но не работает. Браузер почему-то не видит @media

Comment: Разобрался. Надо было в медиа еще ```grid-auto-flow: row;``` прописать.